# OpenGL issue on Galaxy S

Tags: android, opengl-es, textures, galaxy

I've been trying to build myself a little game framework to toy around with writing some basic games for android.  I had been testing on a Sony Arc and Galaxy SII without any issues, but recently I had someone with a Galaxy S do some testing for me and the results were bad.

First run I hadn't set my images sizes to be powers of 2 or square so the majority of the GUI was just big white boxes.  So I resized all my images to be power of 2 AND square to get rid of any problems there, and that fixed it for some images, but I'm finding that some of the objects still show as a white texture.  I can tell it's drawing in the appropriate spot because I can see the white box rotating and moving as it should for the game.

I thought it may have been an issue with the images being 32 bit, so I took all of my images and reduced them to 8 bit and the results are the same, only about half of the textures seem to be working.  I also saw somewhere that mentioned the drawable-nodpi folder, so I moved all my images out of the other folders and put them in there to try that(same results)

I had been looking at this tutorial and it was what I used to base my drawing code off this
http://obviam.net/index.php/texture-mapping-opengl-android-displaying-images-using-opengl-and-squares/

But something I've added or changed must be messing things up, I've included my code below, does anything jump out at anyone that I missed or did wrong?

This is where my Renderer gets created

```
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) 
{        
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);            //Enable Texture Mapping
    gl.glShadeModel(GL10.GL_SMOOTH);            //Enable Smooth Shading
    gl.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f);    //Black Background
    gl.glClearDepthf(1.0f);                     //Depth Buffer Setup
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);            //Enables Depth Testing
    gl.glDepthFunc(GL10.GL_LEQUAL);             //The Type Of Depth Testing To Do
    //Really Nice Perspective Calculations
    gl.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL10.GL_NICEST); 
    // for transparency     
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_BLEND); 
    gl.glBlendFunc(GL10.GL_ONE, GL10.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA); 
}
```

Here's where I'm loading the texture

```
public void loadGLTexture(GL10 gl, Context context, int resourceId) 
{
    // loading texture
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),    resourceId);

    mImageWidth = bitmap.getWidth();
    mImageHeight = bitmap.getHeight();

    // generate one texture pointer
    gl.glGenTextures(1, textures, 0);
    // ...and bind it to our array
    gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);

    // create nearest filtered texture
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_NEAREST);
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);

    //Different possible texture parameters, e.g. GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);//i added
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);//i added


    // Use Android GLUtils to specify a two-dimensional texture image from our bitmap 
    GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);

    // Clean up
    bitmap.recycle();
}
```

And this is where I do my Draw

```
public void draw(GL10 gl, float x, float y, float z, float angle, float percentageScale) {
    gl.glPushMatrix();              
    gl.glLoadIdentity();

    gl.glTranslatef(x,y,z);                            

    gl.glScalef(mXScale*percentageScale, mYScale*percentageScale, 1);

    gl.glRotatef(angle, 0, 0, 1);

    // bind the previously generated texture
    gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);

    // Point to our buffers
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

    // Set the face rotation
    gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CW);

    // Point to our vertex buffer
    gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer);
    gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, textureBuffer);

    // Draw the vertices as triangle strip
    gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, vertices.length / 3);

    //Disable the client state before leaving
    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

    gl.glPopMatrix();
}
```

I have a base class (called textures) that does the drawing for all of my sprites, but for some reason some of them just never seem to get drawn on the Galaxy S and I end up with white boxes for them.

Any ideas?

PS advice on better ways to do this are certainly welcome, I'll be the first to admit that I'm new to OpenGL

Comment: Anybody out there seen this before?  I'm still stuck on this one.